# VStack is not fitting in ContentView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11

I created a app with SwiftUI
I have used this code to layout my view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                Image("Hello")
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

but VStack is not fit to contentView

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add .resizable() to your Image.

Answer (score 0):

wrap a ScrollView{} around it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(0 ..< 5) { item in
      ScrollView{
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            Image("Hello")
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain with complete code?
I did't understand

Comment: you also have to press the **play** button at the bottom right. Or run it at the simulator, for the scroll to work

Comment: I don't required ScrollView for VStack

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is? Your content is too big, therefor you have to create a scrollview, so you can scroll your content

Comment: The use of the `aspectRatio` modifier implies the desire to scale the image to fit, but the `aspectRatio` modifier (by itself) does not make the `Image` resizable.